# Marquee get stopped after some time in widget

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

In my widget I am using a Marquee Textview which is working fine in the beginning. But after sometime,it stops moving. I think this is happening when i am switching the desktop in the emulator.But anyway i need this to be moving every time.Please give me a solution.

Answer (score 0):

No, it has repeating limit. Add `android:marqueeRepeatLimit="1000"` to your TextView, or `textView.setMarqueeRepeatLimit(1000);` in your Java code.